# Getting error bad operand types for binary operator '>' first type: double [] second type: int

Tags: java

So I am completing a project for my professor in school and I keep getting this error code for my project.  Here is my code:

```
    if(bandOrder[counter] > counterMax) {
        counterMax = bandOrder[counter].length;
    }
}
```

Comment: `bandOrder[counter]` returns an array. you are trying to compare an array to counterMax value.

Comment: It can be helpful to include the error output of the compiler along with your code.

Comment: Which error code?

Answer (score 0):

It seens like `bandOrder` is a 2d array `double[][]` and counterMax is a primitive `int`.
So your code `bandOrder[counter]` returned an array `double[]` 
 
It ended up comparing `double[]` with a `int` which is not allowed in java, so you get a exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(bandOrder[counter].length > counterMax) {
   counterMax = bandOrder[counter].length;
  }
}
```

Is this what you are trying to check and achieve?

As evident from the error log, you are certainly comparing an array `bandOrder[counter]` to an int `counterMax`. Make the above changes and it should run just fine. (*if the same logic applies to your application*)

Comment: Thank you for your swift response.  The only thing is now  get an error message saying Main.java:40: error: variable counter might not have been initialized
      bandOrder = new double [counter][];

Comment: @Corbin you will have to initialize the variable `counter` with something like `counter = 0` or the value of `counter` has to be passed as an argument if being used in a method. You might have declared `counter` but the error clearly indicates that there is no value assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are attempting to find the maximum length in your array of arrays `bandOrder`. You ***could*** do

```
if (bandOrder[counter].length > counterMax) {
    counterMax = bandOrder[counter].length;
}
```

or just

```
counterMax = Math.max(counterMax, bandOrder[counter].length);
```